# Type that can hold the product of two size_t

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

I have two `size_t` integers and need to take their product. In what type should I store the result?

```
#include <limits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    typedef std::size_t size_t;
    typedef unsigned long long product_t;

    std::vector<double> a(100000);
    std::vector<double> b(100000);

    size_t na {a.size()};
    size_t nb {b.size()};

    product_t prod = na * nb;

    std::cout << prod << std::endl;
}
```

It looks like gcc defines `size_t` as an `unsigned long long` so I am not guaranteed I will be able to store the product... any alternatives?

**Edit:**

The point here is that I am developing a library that needs to handle vectors of an arbitrary size, compute some statistic on it

```
double stat = computeStatisticOnVectors(a, b);
```

and then compute the following:

```
double result = stat / prod
```

Comment: Something I've seen in the Windows headers is a struct called [ULARGE_INTEGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713(v=vs.85).aspx) which is designed to hold extremely large numbers. That might help you out.

Comment: Fairly meaningless, size_t represents the amount of memory you can allocate.  Multiplying two 64-bit processors doesn't get you a 128-bit processor.

Comment: @HansPassant it also represent a number of data points you can store, and in some cases it makes sense to define operations on these data points counts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve with your code.

If you are later on going to use the value as a `size_t` (in other words, for sizing a vector, allocating memory, or some such), then you probably should do some checks that it's not overflowing, but store the value as a `size_t`. You won't be able to use a bigger type anyway, if the purpose is to create a new object based on the size.

If you are doing something like "calculating the number of possible combinations from these X vectors", then using a floating point type will probably be "good enough".

Comment: I edited my question with more details, indeed instead of `stat / prod` I can probably do `stat / na / nb`. How much precision would I loose here?

Comment: Well, if the result is a `double` from your `stat` calculation, then if `prod` is the result of `double prod = (double)size_a * size_b;`, you are not like to lose any precision over the integer version of that calculation, since the only time it makes a difference at all is if `prod` is larger than 53 bits (and the lowest bits aren't zeros) - and at that point, you are probably not going to notice much of a difference in the output. We are talking 9E+15 or so, so the "loss" will be around 1E-16 times the result.

Comment: Also, doing two individual divides would work, again as long as the result is not more than 2^53 [with non-zero lowest bits], you won't lose any precision. Of course, the result is only precise to 53 bits whatever you do, so around 53/(log(10)/log(2)) = 16 digits.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered not restricting yourself to a primitive type? If it's important to your application that such huge size_type values are handled, why not create a custom type which holds both original values?

Comment: I was indeed considering ways to avoid taking this product (and I guess it must be possible) but hoped there would be a lazy way to store the result in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Up until 128 bits, and assuming you don't need much portability, you may just use built-in types such as `uint128_t` (supported at least by gcc and clang on x86_64 platforms).

If you wish for more portability than this, then 128-bits integers are not standard, so you will need to:

1. Define your own, a pair of 64-bits integer with overload operators would work
2. Use an existing library, such as GMP (LGPL though, but much more generic)
3. *From Marc Glisse:* Boost.Multiprecision (without the license issue)

Of course, if you could simply eliminate this requirement it would be easier; this product you are computing does not seem to mean much in itself, so just doing `stat / na / nb` might well be enough.

Comment: "GNU License": LGPL, please be precise. If you are allergic, you could mention Boost.Multiprecision which provides a portable `int128_t` type.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you're multiplying 100000 and 100000 (rather untypically large values for sizes), where apparently you would want to obtain 10^10 exactly as a result.

As a rough calculation based on 2^10 ~= 10^3, divide the 10's exponent by 3 and multiply by 10 to get the number of bits. Now 10*10/3 is roughly 33, which means you need more than 32 bits, which means 64 bits. Thus, use a 64-bit type.

In addition to being 64-bit the type should be signed, because it's a good idea to use signed types for numbers (otherwise, due to implicit conversions you risk inadvertently using modular arithmetic, with hard to track down bugs). So, the built-in type that you're looking for is – signed 64-bit integer – oh, that's `long long`.

Or you can use one of the type aliases from `<stdint.h>`.

That said, why on Earth are you multiplying large sizes, and why do you need the result as an exact integer?

Comment: I am writing a library, and users can pass vectors of any size they want. 100000 was just an example here, but I could possibly receive two vectors of size `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`, and would have to deal with it. On my system that is already two 64-bits integer, so I would need an 128-bits. But ideally I'd like this to be portable whatever the kind of size_t on the system.
As I said in an other comment I am also considering getting rid of the product.

Answer (score 0):

Your statistics will be computed on vectors, which size will not exceed size_t capacity.
I think it's enough to detect overflow in your case.
I can think of a double conversion of each size, then compare the two products (size_t based product vs double product)